# left padding is not equal on different type of elements

Tags: html, css

I've got a bit of an issue with the left padding on a text input and and select input not being equal. The select input has slightly more padding on the left than the text box.
I've tried explicitly setting the padding the same for both elements but it didn't work. I'm using IE 10

[image: left padding not equal]

Any suggestions as to how I can make them equal?

```
<style>
  .reportControl{
    padding-left: 3px;
  }
<style>



<select name="dd_reports" id="dd_reports" class="reportControl">
    <option value="3">Actual and Planned Projects</option>
</select>

 <input name="tx_reportName" type="text" value="Actual and Planned Projects" id="tx_reportName" class="reportControl" />
```

Comment: can you share some code?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: There we go, code added. Thanks for the markdown!!

Comment: I tried it in fiddle, seems to be the default behavior! You can try increasing padding of your text box to match with the `select`

Answer (score 0):

You can give the next `input` a `border-left` of 3px and set the color to be the same background to make it blend in.

```
#tx_reportName {
  border-left: 3px solid white;
  border-top: 0px
}
```